# 'get_masterTableView' is not in Grid found in NestedView

Tags: javascript, telerik, radgrid

I Have a grid ( "gridA" ), In Nested View has another Grid ( "gridB" )

In "gridB" has a RadMenu and when the the rad menu is clicked there is a js function to be called see below code sample.

```
 function missionGridRadMenuClicking(rowIndex, missionGridId) {
            var grid = $find(missionGridId);

            var masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
```

Last line of above code get following error.

> "Object doesn't support property or method 'get_masterTableView'"

I have attached the grid properties when debugging with IE. when debugging also I can not see the `get_masterTableView()`.

attached image : http://www.telerik.com/ClientsFiles/383268_nestedGrid-properties-and-methods.jpg

Anybody have an idea about this issue. the main different I see is this grid in a NestedView of another grid.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: is the `missionGridRadMenuClicking` function a handler for menu's `itemClicking` event?

Comment: are you using RadControls for MVC or RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX ? can you brief about it ?

Comment: missionGridRadMenuClicking is onclick event and I am using ASP.NET AJAX.

Comment: Where from you got `menuItemClicking` event handler signature?  Check for documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/menu-onclientitemclicking.html